# Output single character in C

Tags: c, character, string-formatting

When printing a single character in a C program, must I use "%1s" in the format string? Can I use something like "%c"?

Answer (score 103):

yes, `%c` will print a single char:

```
printf("%c", 'h');
```

also, `putchar`/`putc` will work too. From "man putchar":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
int putchar(int c);

* fputc() writes the character c, cast to an unsigned char, to stream.
* putc() is equivalent to fputc() except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
* putchar(c); is equivalent to putc(c,stdout).
```

EDIT:

Also note, that if you have a string, to output a single char, you need get the character in the string that you want to output. For example:

```
const char *h = "hello world";
printf("%c\n", h[4]); /* outputs an 'o' character */
```

Comment: I am using MS C 6.0 and it does not work. Gives no error either.

Comment: Could you post some non-working sample code?  Make sure the 'c' is lowercase in the '%c'.

Comment: did you try copy and pasting my example. %c should work given that the parameter is of the correct type (a char, not a string).

Answer (score 24):

Be careful of difference between `'c'` and `"c"`

`'c'` is a char suitable for formatting with %c

`"c"` is a char* pointing to a memory block with a length of 2 (with the null terminator).

Comment: Technically, "c" is a char* with a length of 4 (or whatever your pointer size is) that points to a block of memory with 2 characters in it ('c' and '\0').  But that's just being pedantic.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, you can use **putc**(int c, FILE *stream), **putchar**(int c) or **fputc**(int c, FILE *stream) for this purpose.

What's important to note is that using any of the above functions is from some to signicantly faster than using any of the format-parsing functions like printf.

Using printf is like using a machine gun to fire one bullet.

Comment: `printf()` for single char, is like buying a book to get a piece of paper.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to output a single character is to simply use the `putchar` function. After all, that's it's sole purpose and it cannot do anything else. It cannot be simpler than that.

Answer (score 3):

```
char variable = 'x';  // the variable is a char whose value is lowercase x

printf("<%c>", variable); // print it with angle brackets around the character
```