# Unable to find error in code that write every word of a string in a new line

Tags: c

I am writing a code that takes a string as input and prints every word in the string in a newline.

I am using pointer arithmetic for this purpose

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *s;
  s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%[^\n]", s);
  s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (*s == ' ') {
      printf("\n");
    } else {
      printf("%s", s);
    }
    s++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
i am a beginner. \n
```

Output:

```
i am a beginner \n   
am a beginnerm a beginner \n   
a beginner \n
beginnereginnerginnerinnernnernererr
```

Comment: You’re printing the whole string from the current position to the end each time, not just one character.

Comment: Change this `printf("%s", s);` to `printf("%c", *s);`

Comment: Why not use `free()` (after all the trouble to `realloc()`)? It's only a little bit more trouble and it pays to be thorough :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output single character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310032/output-single-character-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `%s` you need `%c` to print a single character. Besides that, you don't need to free the memory you get from `malloc` since `realloc` takes care of that, but you *have to* free the memory you got from `realloc`. Yes, the OS will clean up after you, but it is best to release the resources you acquired. In order to do the `free` we are going to not change the value of `s`, instead we are going to copy it. Here is the fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char* s;
  s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%[^\n]", s);
  char* p = s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
  while (*p != '\0') {
    if (*p == ' ') {
      printf("\n");
    } else {
      printf("%c", *p);
    }
    ++p;
  }
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
My awesome input
```

Output:

```
My
awesome
input
```

A few points for you to consider. If the user adds multiple space characters in between words or adds something like `'\t'`, your program doesn't handle the case correctly.

Comment: Do suggest OP to `free()` dynamic memory to avoid memory leakage. Also due to `s++` `s` no longer points initial dynamic memory address, to free it, need to keep track of initial `s`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say its not very logical to reinvent the wheel unless you need some extra functionality or portability. Same can be done more reliably like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);

    char *to_free = s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    char *word;

    while ((word = strsep(&s, " \t")) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", word);

    free(to_free);

    return 0;
}
```

This also allows you to keep track of tabs as well as spaces(as you are considering words). Notice the argument passed to `strsep`, its a space and a tab. You could easily separate words using `,`, `.` etc as well by just adding these delimeters to the `strsep` argument.

Also it is a good practice to free the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

if you use printf with "%s" it prints out the entire string all the way to \0.

that's why you see the entire sentence in every line (minus a few characters from the start).

the way you used pointers in this code, I'm guessing you're trying print out individual characters, so just switch "%s" with "%c"