# Unable to print the first character in a string in c

Tags: c

im having a strange issue when trying to access the first character in a string.
Im attempting to write a program that reads info from a file and separates it into a struct. however when i attempt to access a specific character in a string, i get a strange error. below is the error and code snippets.

Error:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:332:43: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
332 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

code snippets. (not the whole program, just the lines that seem to be having issues)

```
char lineArray[40][101];

strcpy(lineArray[lineNum], validLine);

printf(lineArray[lineNum][0]);
```

when attempting to print the first character in an entry in lineArray, i get the above error. I get the same error when using strcpy in order to try and copy the first character into a different string. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a foolish quetion, im still pretty new to C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output single character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310032/output-single-character-in-c)

Comment: @BenYoo no.... not `%d` To print a string it is `printf("%s", lineArray[lineNum]);`

Comment: If you want to print a newline after the string, you could also do `puts(lineArray[lineNum]);`

Comment: oh... if you just want to print the first character it is `printf("%c", lineArray[lineNum][0]);`

Comment: " I get the same error when using strcpy in order to try and copy the first character into a different string." Well, `strcpy` **can not** copy a single character. If you want to create a new string from the first character you can do: `char newstr[2] = { 0 }; newstr[0] =  lineArray[lineNum][0];`

Comment: The first parameter to printf must be a string, not a char.

Comment: @BenYoo If you agree that your comment is wrong, please delete it

Comment: Read the man page for `putchar()` to output a single character.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to change

> `printf(lineArray[lineNum][0]);`

to `printf("%c", lineArray[lineNum][0]);`

Because the definition of printf function is `int printf(const char *format, ...)`.
The first parameter must be *format* string,
and the second parameter must be variables to be substituted into *format*.

On my recommended code, "%c" is meant to tell printf function to print a char variable that must be passed as a next variable.

Comment: Why `printf()` for a single character? Wouldn't `putchar (lineArray[lineNum][0]);` do the job without invoking the variadic printf function? `printf()` will work, just a bit heavy handed. Or for the first character, `putchar (*lineArray[lineNum]);` would suffice.

Comment: How about `putchar()` instead of `printf("%c")`?

Comment: `printf("%c")` would be better for right now since it has an easier approach to the language. Whenever OP is getting used to the language and feeling necessary to care of performance, OP may choose to use `putchar()` or other less-overhead functions.